# How to use @SecurityDomain in Jboss 6?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jboss-eap-6

In my standalone-full.xml I got this security-domain:

```
<security-domain name="my-security-domain" cache-type="default">  
   <authentication>  
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required" >  
             <module-option name="usersProperties" value="/path/to/users.properties"/>  
             <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="/path/to/roles.properties"/>  
        </login-module>  
   </authentication>  
</security-domain>
```

...but it does not seems to be picked up from my code, in a MDB I got:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageMDB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/DLQ"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
@SecurityDomain("my-security-domain")
@RunAsPrincipal("123")
//@RunAs("abc")

@PermitAll
public class MessageMDB implements MessageListener 
{

    @EJB
    BeanLocal beanLocal;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) 
    {

        String messageString = beanLocal.returnAString( "yada" );
```

...and in my SLSB I got:

```
@Stateless(name="aStatelessBean")
@SecurityDomain("my-security-domain")
@RolesAllowed("abc")
public class Bean implements BeanRemote, BeanLocal {

    @Resource
    protected SessionContext sessionContext;

    public Bean() 
    {
    }


    @Override
    public String returnAString(String parameter) 
    {
```

To me this says that the MDB should call the SLSB as the user "123".
Since user 123 is configured like this in user.properties:

```
123=qwe
```

...and in roles.properties

```
123=abc,def
```

...he should be allowed to call the SLSB but I just get:

Failure in caller transaction.: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public abstract java.lang.String my.BeanLocal.returnAString(java.lang.String) of bean: aStatelessBean is not allowed

It only works if I add this to the MDB:

```
@RunAs("abc")
```

But of course I would it to be picked up by the configuration in the "my-security-domain" instead.

Do you guys see what I miss?

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: See the documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html-single/how_to_configure_identity_management/

Answer (score 0):

To login to the context within a MDB and check roles and so on I needed to do like this in my JBoss. I just did not manage to do it in some other way.

```
public static String ROLE = "abc";

@Resource  
MessageDrivenContext sessionContext;

private static SecurityClient getClientLogin() throws Exception
{
       final SecurityClient client = SecurityClientFactory.getSecurityClient();
        client.setSimple("123", "qwe");
        return client;
}

...

SecurityClient client = getClientLogin();
client.login();

...

System.out.println( sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal() );
System.out.println( sessionContext.isCallerInRole( ROLE ) );
```

Think that was it.
If you see any errors or improvements please notify me and I will try to correct it/add it.
Best regards
Fredrik